# How to find address of Buffer in Android(Java)

Tags: java, android, buffer

How can we find or generate an address for a Buffer (or memory streams ,...) in Android programming with java?

And specially use that address to point out where to write or read data?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Java abstracts you away from the low level details on where/how a buffer gets created.  A memory address is meaningless from a developer's perspective because the JVM is free to move your object around.  An example of this occurring is via garbage collection.

You just need to make sure your buffer can be referenced by whoever reads/writes from it.  Depending on the scope, you require, you could:

a. Make the buffer a singleton.  Access it globally by returning it from a static method.  Not threadsafe.

b. Wrap it in a ThreadLocal if you want to access it statically in the same thread, expose it with a static method.  You can have an instance of your Buffer per thread.  Remember to remove() the value of the ThreadLocal before the thread dies.

c. Pass it around via method parameters.

d. If you use an DI container such as Spring, wire it in as a dependency to the objects that need it, depending on the scope you need.

Comment: Thanks, can u see this link? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535217/how-to-store-out-put-of-ffmpeg-in-buffers-or-etc-instead-of-phone-storage-in-and) actually I asked this question for that topic. I have heard about memory protocol . Isn't any way to achieve using buffers like a directory?